# Logs when running Confluent dockers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am running Confluent Kafka docker cp-all-in-one.
I want to insert some topic data to MS SQL server. I create new DB and table. Using Confluent Control Center I added JdbcSinkConnector.

Connector config:

```
"name": "jdbc2users",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"errors.log.enable": "true",
"errors.log.include.messages": "true",
"topics": [
    "users"
],
"errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
"connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.55:1433;databaseName=ktest;",
"connection.user": "kuser",
"connection.password": "*****",
"insert.mode": "INSERT",
"auto.create": "true",
"auto.evolve": "true",
"max.retries": "10"
```

Connector is starting but in few seconds change status to Degraded. I already tried to change connection URL, but always failing.
Where I can find this connector log files?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The errors should be visible in Kafka Connect's logs.

Comment: `docker logs <image_name>`?

Comment: Where "connect" is the name of the service in the cp-all-in-one.yml file. 

$ docker-compose logs connect

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can run "confluent local log connect" and scroll to the bottom, then work your way back up.